# Apple Keynote doesnt play in most of my browsers

Tags: google-chrome, keynote, internet-explorer

I made a presentation with a simple transition effects and tried to export that presentation to HTML format.

But when I tried to open it on my MacBook, I found, that it doesnt work in Chrome, but works fine in Opera, Firefox and Safari. It show me the preloader and the black screen then in Chrome.

And then I tried to open it on Windows and found, that it works ONLY in Firefox... Chrome, Opera and IE8 dont want to play it...:( And show me the black screen only.

Is that normal or I do something wrong? I need it to play in IE and Chrome for most of our employees...

Answer (score 1):

### Export to QuickTime / Movie

Your best option is to **export the presentation as a QuickTime movie**. This will create an MPEG4 formatted file that can be played on a wide range of devices and operating systems:

**Keynote.app > File (menu) > Export To… > QuickTime**

[image: Keynote Export to QuickTime options]

### Compress with Handbrake

After exporting your presentation, consider compressing the resulting movie file using [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr). Handbrake will dramatically reduce the file size and broaden the number of supported playback devices.

### View with Browser or VLC

Many web browsers across different operating systems can also natively play back MPEG4 files; so for many employees a web browser such as UE or Chrome will be enough to view the presentation.

Alternatively Mac, Windows, and Linux users can all play exported movies using the free application [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** As of Chrome 53.0.2785.116 this bug has been fixed, and Keynote presentations exported as HTML now work properly (see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=528681)

*Old answer:*
Since the release of Chrome 45, Keynote presentations exported as an html file are broken. I opened an issue on Google Code about it [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=528480), which was eventually closed and merged into a larger issue, titled "[jQuery Mobile stays in loading state](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=528681)". That issue, as of the writing of this post, has not been fixed in Google Chrome for Mac or Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[Keynote for iCloud](http://www.apple.com/iwork-for-icloud/) may be a solution to look at if you wish to maintain better control over transition timing and flow of the presentation.  Please note, however, that it is only supported by modern browsers.  See note below.

Otherwise, as [Graham Miln](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/214531/120171) states in his answer, a movie would be a better choice.  There are a few settings to explore when exporting the movie to control timing and playback.  One is encouraged to experiment with these settings, perhaps even exporting a few movies to review.

From Apple:

> #### Supported browsers For a Mac:
>
> - Safari 6.0.3 (or later)
> - Google Chrome 27.0.1 (or later)
>
> For a Windows computer:
>
> - Internet Explorer 10.0.9 (or later)
> - Google Chrome 27.0.1 (or later)